# How i can change the background in vnc

Tags: vnc, x11vnc, tightvnc, vncviewer

Is there a way to change the background in the vnc

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

This setting has to be enabled from the server side with the `-solid` flag.

```
x11vnc -solid black
```

or whatever color you like. Note that there seem to be some limitations depending on the desktop environment: [Manpages](https://linux.die.net/man/1/x11vnc)

Comment: can I change the ubuntu background with a different one?

Comment: No, except by changing the wallpaper of the host user.

Comment: Ok how i can do that, the host machine is docker image running on my machine

Comment: @AmrKamel As I see the Ubuntu logo, I assume Unity as desktop environment: [Change wallpaper from CLI in Unity](https://askubuntu.com/questions/66914/how-to-change-desktop-background-from-command-line-in-unity). In general it depends on the DE.